# capturing a specific value from a cookie javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie set up which has data stored in the following format:

```
{"g":"776","f":"88876","hit":"true","TESTVALUE":"this is the value i want to capture"}
```

I want to capture "TESTVALUE" in its own variable.

I am using this script to actually capture the cookie data (where the cookie is called "chocolateChip":

```
var getCookie = function (name) {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
} // code indentation

var cookie = getCookie(chocolateChip);
```

Im then using the following script to pass the "testvalue" string to its own variable:

```
var test = cookie.TESTVALUE;
```

However this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie value is a JSON string, which you need to parse to get an actual JS object.

Try this:

```
var cookie = getCookie(chocolateChip);
var test = JSON.parse(cookie).TESTVALUE;
```

Or, if you need to access more properties:

```
var cookie = getCookie(chocolateChip);
var cookieObject = JSON.parse(cookie);
var testValue = cookieObject.TESTVALUE;
```